# R programming help on writing functions

Tags: r, function, division

I am trying to write a code that shows a vector who will only show elements who are not divisible by 2,3, or 7.

```
function2 <- function(x){
    k <- length(x)
    for(i in 1:x){
        if(i%%2!=0 | i%%3!=0 | i%%7!=0){
            return x[i]
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me error. 
Can anyone help?

I'm still very new to writing codes and always have trouble doing so.

Any suggestions to improve would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

I made some changes and another warning message occurred.

```
function2 <- function(x) {
    k <- length(x)
    for(i in 1:x){
        if(i%%2!=0 | i%%3!=0 | i%%7!=0) {
            show(x[i])
        } else {
            i <- i+1
        }
        print(x[i])
    }
}

x <- 1:100
function2(1:100)
## [1] 1
## [1] 1
## Warning message:
## In 1:x : numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used

> foo <- function(x) {
+     x[(x %%2 != 0) | (x %% 3 != 0) | (x %% 7 != 0)]
+ }
> foo(1:100)
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
[20]  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38
[39]  39  40  41  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58
[58]  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77
[77]  78  79  80  81  82  83  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
[96]  98  99 100
```

Comment: Faith notice that the beginning line line characters were removed from your code previously.  Otherwise the burden to do so is ont hose helping you.  Can you clean up your code (remove `>` and `+` from the beginning lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the "and" operator `&` instead of "or" `|`.  Also, there's no need to loop, you can take advantage of R's vectorization.

```
foo <- function(x) {
    x[(x %% 2 != 0) & (x %% 3 != 0) & (x %% 7 != 0)]
}
foo(1:50)
# [1]  1  5 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47
```

You can also do it without writing a function

```
x <- 1:50
x[(x %% 2 != 0) & (x %% 3 != 0) & (x %% 7 != 0)]
# [1]  1  5 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but the question wrote 2,3 or 7. and then when i use it it still gives me foo(1:100) the set of values frm 1:100 T.T

Comment: If you want the numbers that are not divisible by 2, 3, or 7, then you should be using `&` It would be "not divisible by 2 and not divisible by 3 and not divisible by 7"

Comment: i get it now! that has to do with de morgan's laws!! thank you so much Mr Richard! merci beaucoup!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is already a vectorized solution on the table and it is far preferable but I thought the task of building a loop that actually runs would also be useful. You initialized a loop-length value, `k`, but never used it, rather looping on `1:x`. That's the first basic error (beyond than using `"|"` rather than `"&"` which has already been pointed out). And another error was not keeping an accumulator of valid results which could be returned after running the loop. And the third logical error was testing values of the loop-index rather than values of `x`:

```
function2=function(x){
    k=length(x); val <- c()
    for(i in 1:k){    # probably should have used seq_along(x), and skip 'k'
         if(!( x[i]%%2==0 | x[1]%%3==0 | x[i]%%7==0)){  # could have used `"||"`
                       val <- c(val,x[i])            }
                 }
     return (val)     }  # don't need the return(), could just evaluate `val`

 x<-(1:100)
 function2(1:100)
[1]  1  3  5  9 11 13 15 17 19 23 25 27 29 31 33 37 39 41 43 45 47 51 53 55 57 59
[27] 61 65 67 69 71 73 75 79 81 83 85 87 89 93 95 97 99
```

Comment: Note there was another error in `return x[i]`.  No parentheses

Comment: Right. Now he has your proper example and my "Fortran"-code, but at least I added a complementary logical test. I see the combo of check-mark and upvotes lets your answer float to the top where it belongs.

Comment: thanks a million! without you guys to help, i wouldnt have manage to solve my question!  i really appreciate it! (: